# Double Drywall: Stud is behind Door Frame

Tags: drywall, studs

I am planning to hang a second layer of drywall along one side of an 18' hallway for soundproofing purposes (green glue between drywall layers) and I just want to make sure I am doing it correctly as it's my first time working with drywall.

The middle of the hall should be fairly straightforward but I have some concerns about the ends. Attached is a pic of one end of the hall wherein the stud (16" OC, marked with painter's tape) is behind a door frame. I know that, ideally, a sheet of drywall should be screwed onto studs at both ends but this is not possible in this case as the door frame is in the way.

I don't want to leave the sheet just hanging unscrewed on one side and and I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks for reading.
-Reg

[image]

Comment: Are your sure there's not a stud in the corner? 16" o.c. is a guideline, but not something to verify your tape measure with, especially at corners and around doors

Comment: There is almost certainly another stud at the corner as @mmathis says.  Otherwise the existing drywall would not be attached at that end.  Try pounding a nail or drilling a small hole through the existing drywall near the corner and see if you hit a stud.

Comment: What did you use to find the studs? Surprised anything would pick up the jack stud but not one in the corner...

Comment: Should probably consider taking the trim off, instead of drywalling up to it. Then rip it, to fit up to the new wall surface.

Comment: Thanks mmathis. There definitely was a stud at the corner where the wall meets the ceiling.

Comment: I am using a magnetic stud finder as well as an electronic one. Still no accessible stud along the door frame though. Seriously considering your suggestion, Tahwos. Thanks!